# Add something about talk privilege to chat FAQ

Tags: feature-request, chat

I requested permission to a chat room the other day. While awaiting access, it shows the message:

> Only users nominated by the room owner may talk here. See the faq for more information. You have requested talk privileges in this room; please be patient while the room owner processes your request.

Out of curiosity, I clicked the link to the faq. The problem is, it doesn't seem to mention locked rooms at all. Anywhere. It does mention owner permissions, but that's not the same thing as talk privileges.

I completely understand the privilege thing. I'm sure most other people will too, after reading the blurb in the room itself. It's pretty self-explanatory, really. However, if there's *going* to be a link to the faq, it should at least have something to say about it.